# Setting up video array view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

Very new to Xcode. I'm trying to make a live wallpaper app. I have my main project basically all working, couple different views, navigation controllers, ect... I finally got the preview/save viewController to work and be able to save the MOV file as a live photo.
But now my problem is linking multiple MOV files to different buttons to load which ever MOV into the preview/save viewController. This is what I have so far.

```
struct FilePaths {
static let documentsPath : AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory,.userDomainMask,true)[0] as AnyObject
struct VidToLive {
    static var livePath = FilePaths.documentsPath.appending("/")
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var livePhotoView: PHLivePhotoView!
    {
    didSet {
        loadVideoWithVideoURL(Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")!)
    }
}
```

So I have the view set to the IBOutlet with the specific path of "video.mov", is there a way I can set a button to load "video2.mov" in that view without having to recreate everything? My first thought while making this was have a ton of different viewControllers with their own MOV in each one...(told you I'm new)...but that definitely cant be the answer. I'm learning as i go :/ ... thank you in advance.

Comment: Is "I may have set this up wrong" really the best description of the problem to use as a subject line for this question?

Comment: 100% right. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an array of video file names:

```
let vids = ["video", "video2", "video3"]
```

And suppose you have the same number of buttons, hooked up to your view controller as an *outlet collection*:

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoButtons:[UIButton]!
```

And assume that each of those buttons is also set up with an *action* connection to your view controller, so that the same method is called when any button is pressed. Then when a button is pressed you can look to see *which* button it is, look to see *which* video name that is, and act accordingly:

```
@IBAction func doVideoButton(_ sender : UIButton) {
    if let index = self.videoButtons.firstIndex(of:sender) {
        let videoName = self.vids[index]
        // now you know the name, load that video and show it!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Iv been away from my computer and currently at work. I will try to set this up tomorrow morning when I get off.... so let me get this straight. I will delete the current outlet I have (or at least comment it out) pop in the “let vids” line in. Reconnect the view to the new IBOutlet how you wrote . Then add each button to a IBAction calling on which video to load like. “let video.mov = self.vids[index]”?  Thank you so much for the response. I will let you know how it goes!!

Comment: ok, so iv tried to mess around with this method and searched videos and the internet on setting up arrays. I guess i dont get it.  the IBOutlet i have set to this viewController is no an outlet collection and wont let me make an outlet collect for some reason. I assume i would have to substitute the line i have under my original outlet loadVideoWithVideoURL, because that is a specific video linked directly to that view.... correct? thank you again.

Comment: Sorry, so now what's the question? Is it that you don't know how to make an outlet collection? Well, my code above shows you how.

Comment: (Remember I don’t know much about any of this) iv very sorry if I’m not understanding. It will only let me connect the buttons as actions when I control drag and the “connection” drop down is  grayed out so I can’t click to change to outlet or outlet collection.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're doing at this point, and I can't guide your hand on the mouse every step of the way. You need to learn how to make connections between storyboard and view controller. There are so many tutorials and books and videos about this...

Comment: I understand. Thanks for you time.